# ubuntu docker not work

Tags: ubuntu, docker, iptables

I'm run command with `dockerd` in win10 subsystem(ubuntu 16.04LTS),but it's not work and shows the following content:

> WARN[2018-06-08T06:48:49.740127000+08:00] Could not set daemon root propagation to shared, this is not generally critical but may cause some functionality to not work or fallback to less desirable behavior  dir=/var/lib/docker error="invalid argument"
>   INFO[2018-06-08T06:48:49.753965500+08:00] libcontainerd: started new docker-containerd process  pid=386
>   INFO[0000] starting containerd                           module=containerd revision=773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88 version=v1.0.3
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.content.v1.content"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.content.v1
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
>   WARN[0000] failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs  error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter" module=containerd
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
>   WARN[0000] could not use snapshotter btrfs in metadata plugin  error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter" module="containerd/io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.differ.v1.walking"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.differ.v1
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.gc.v1
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.content"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.diff"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.events"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.images"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.monitor.v1
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.runtime.v1
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.version"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
>   INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection"...  module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
>   INFO[0000] serving...                                    address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd-debug.sock" module="containerd/debug"
>   INFO[0000] serving...                                    address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock" module="containerd/grpc"
>   INFO[0000] containerd successfully booted in 0.052238s   module=containerd
>   INFO[2018-06-08T06:48:49.848907600+08:00] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2
>   INFO[2018-06-08T06:48:49.875020600+08:00] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds
>   WARN[2018-06-08T06:48:49.875364600+08:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup memory limit
>   WARN[2018-06-08T06:48:49.875838500+08:00] Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts
>   WARN[2018-06-08T06:48:49.876236300+08:00] Unable to find blkio cgroup in mounts
>   WARN[2018-06-08T06:48:49.877373300+08:00] Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts
>   WARN[2018-06-08T06:48:49.888299100+08:00] mountpoint for pids not found
>   INFO[2018-06-08T06:48:49.890328400+08:00] Loading containers: start.
>   WARN[2018-06-08T06:48:49.906233900+08:00] Running modprobe nf_nat failed with message: `modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft/modules.dep.bin'
>   modprobe: WARNING: Module nf_nat not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft`, error: exit status 1
>   WARN[2018-06-08T06:48:49.934145900+08:00] Running modprobe xt_conntrack failed with message: `modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft/modules.dep.bin'
>   modprobe: WARNING: Module xt_conntrack not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft`, error: exit status 1
>   Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
>   Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
>    (exit status 3)

It's seems to be iptables problem, and I tried `sudo apt-get install iptables` but not valid.

How can I run the docker daemon?

Answer (score 1):

The WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) is just a "light" linux, not a full one.

You can do some simple stuff there, but it is not guaranteed to work. I think this system is more like a proof of concept, that it's actually working. It s not designed to be a full linux, just to run some simple commands within.

`docker` is a really heavy program, doing virtualization and other low level stuff. It heavily relies on some kernel functions / modules you cannot emulate within WSL. The `iptables`, for example, need a full working kernel with low level networking and thus fails to install.

Answer (score 0):

Dockerd is a wrapper around LXC-containers. So LXC is a wrapper around linux kernel namespaces.
Linux subsystem  for windows have not running full linux kernel, and maybe have no namespace functionality inside. 
If you need to run containers on Windows - try docker-machine.